# directive with ng-metadata, getting "html" from elements within a directive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to convert a directive over to `ng-metadata` using the `@Directive` syntax, but I'm having trouble figuring out a specific piece. The directive calls for `element.html()`, but I cannot seem to figure out where that would be on the new directive.

This is the directive;

```
angular.module('ngContenteditable', ['ngSanitize']).
    directive('contenteditable', ['$sce','$sanitize', function($sce, $sanitize) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '?ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                if (!ngModel) return; 

                ngModel.$render = function () {
                    element.html($sanitize(ngModel.$viewValue || ''));
                };

                element.on('blur keyup change', function () {
                    scope.$apply(readViewText);
                });

                function readViewText() {
                    var html = element.html();
                    if (attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>') {
                        html = '';
                    }
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
                }
            }
        };
}]);
```

And so far, this is what I have for the ng-metadata version.

```
import { Directive, Inject, Self, Optional, Input, HostListener } from 'ng-metadata/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[contenteditable]'
})
export class ngDirective {
    @Input() stripBr: string;
    constructor(
        @Inject('ngModel') @Self() @Optional() private ngModel: any,
        @Inject('$sce') private $sce: ng.ISCEService,
        @Inject('$sanitize') private $sanitize: ng.sanitize.ISanitizeService) {
    }

    @HostListener('blur keyup change')
    onNgChange() {

    }

    onReadViewText() {
        let html = this.html(); // ... how do I get the HTML?
    }
}
```

Comment: It likely should be $element service and $element.html(). It isn't specific to ng-metadata. This is how the things are done when code is moved from link function to controller and back.

Comment: But where does `$element` come from?

Comment: From dependency injection. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-

Comment: Thank you so much! Wow, that makes more sense. I always thought it was part of the event parameters. It never occurred to me that it might be a dependency too!! I'll try this out shortly and get back to you, but could you post this as the official answer so I can give credit?

Comment: Sure. You may notice that `link` is no longer welcome in A1.5. I would suggest to take a closer look at ES6/TS class-based development in A1.5 (without ng-metadata) and A2 (I guess you're using ng-metadata for easier migration). The way how ng-metadata handles things will make much more sense then, it just tries to mimic A2 API with controller-centric approach that A1.5 offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class for ng-metadata `@Directive` and `@Component` is a controller class in fact. And directive controllers have local dependencies - `$scope`, `$element`, etc.

`$element` should be injected into constructor as any other dependency and be used like `$element.html()`.

Comment: This worked great. Thank you so much. I feel like a moron, but I'm a moron with working code!